# Swagger на Scala. Не читаются поля модели

Tags: scala, swagger

Я пытаюсь прикрутить `Swagger` к апи. Столкнулся с тем, что не читаются поля у модели. Модель выглядит следующим образом:

```
    @ApiModel(value = "Person", description = "Сущность сотрудника")
    case class PersonEntity(
                           @(ApiModelProperty @field)(value = "Идентификатор сотрудника")
                           id: Long,
                           @(ApiModelProperty @field)(value = "Имя сотрудника")
                           name: String,
                           @(ApiModelProperty @field)(value = "Возраст сотрудника")
                           age: Int)
```

В итоге в Json только заголовок модели, без единого поля

```
"definitions" : {
    "Person" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "description" : "Сущность сотрудника"
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема нашлась не в самом `swagger` а на стыке Scala и Java при конвертации типов из скаловских в джавовские.
**UPD**
Дополнительно не забыть подключить зависимость
`"io.swagger" %% "swagger-scala-module" % "1.0.4"`